# Extracion de una cantidad exacta de valores entre caractares con Preg_Mach

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Hola Tengo un string con valres separado con | y estos valores se mueven de posicion constantemente por lo que realiza un Regex para tomar un mach fijo no es posible por lo que la unica caracteristica es que los dos campos que quiero estan entre | uno tiene 22 caracteres alfanumerico y el otro por igual tiene 10 entre | pero solo es numerico.

Trate algo como esto pero es impreciso puesto que hay ocaciones que me tomas hasta 2 o 3 valores entre | sin que tengan las caracteristicas antes mencionadas.

```
<?php                                                   
$texto='|1000|head|bestfit|1598032550|false|source|CnPu0lPAhxo8EBWEKcehnw|setAttribute|';  
       preg_match('#\|(.{22,22}\|#)|#\|([0-9]{10,10})\|#',$texto,$match);
       print_r($match);
      ?>
```

Necesito solo `|1598032550|` y `|CnPu0lPAhxo8EBWEKcehnw|`, como ya dije estas variable pueden cambiar de posision y tener otras variables en el medio.

Busco este resultado:

```
Array ( [0] => |8yzvD2aNeWA7c4IGUijlbg| [1] => 8yzvD2aNeWA7c4IGUijlbg ) Array ( [1] => |1598032550| [0] => 1598032550 )
```

Gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema esta en tu expresión regular, de hecho tienes varios problemas en ella.

Lo primero que no es un problema sino una sugerencia es que es mas facil utilizar un solo grupo (parentesis) para que te sea mas facil de procesar en tu código.

Otro problema es que los `#` de tu expresión intentan buscar de manera literal un `#` que no existe en tu texto de busqueda.

Para hacer la busqueda de solo números se utiliza `\d` (digit cualquier número del 0 al 9) que es lo mismo que `[0-9]` match con un número del 0 al 9

Para hacer busqueda de texto alfanumérico se utiliza `\w` (any word caracter) que equivale a `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` o simplemente utilizas `[a-zA-Z0-9]` para omitir los underscore `_` también.

Tu expresión quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
(\|\w{22,22}\||\|\d{10,10}\|)
```

Te dejo un sitio donde es muy facil realizar pruebas y contruir tus expresiones regulares de forma interactiva.

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/)

Espero te sea útil, saludos.

Comment: Me funciona muy bien solo que estas incluyendo los | que no me interensan el resultado final.Me imagino que si lo saco de los () deberan eliminarlo.

Comment: Exacto, al sacar los | del parentesis ya obtienes el valor único.  quedaría así: `\|(\w{22,22}|\d{10,10})\|`

Comment: Uso esta pagina para Regex por su sencilles https://pythex.org/

Comment: Fijate use el ultimo  \|(\w{22,22}|\d{10,10})\| y no me saco los valores. Que interesante.

Comment: En términos generales es lo mismo, en algunos casos puedes tener pequeñas variaciones ya que estás utilizando el  interprete de Python, regex te permite utilizar otros interpretes, y es más explicativo, pero también funciona pythex sin problemas! Cuestión de gustos

Comment: Ya veo, tal vez te falte el flag, intenta agregandole el flag g (global)

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con preg_match_all() y este patrón

```
$texto='|1000|head|bestfit|1598032550|false|source|CnPu0lPAhxo8EBWEKcehnw|setAttribute|';  
preg_match_all('#\|([\w]{22})\||\|([\d]{10})\|#', $texto, $match);
print_r($match);
```

Y el resultado:
[image: Resultado]

Comment: Hola Benito, lo aplique tal cual a mi data y no me dio data, usando la recomendacion del Anterior comentario le elimine los # y ya funciona gracias.

Comment: Te recomiendo entonces que marques su respuesta como aceptada, así cualquier usuario que tenga el mismo error podrá encontrar rapidamente la solución, y es la mejor manera de dar las gracias a quien te respondió :) Me alegro que se haya solucionado tu problema!